# Do all [makefile] questions need to have a language tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [makefile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makefile) tag has 19 questions, 3 of which do not have a language tag.  They have already been reviewed and are not closed.  We also don't get very many makefile questions, so I'm not sure if they should be approached any differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Makefiles *are* a domain-specific language.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that [makefile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makefile) is close enough to being a language itself that it does not need another language tag.